# Differentiation of multiple integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives

I have a function z defined as:
$z(\alpha ,\beta )=\int_{0}^{\beta }{\int_{0}^{\alpha }{(\omega +\varepsilon )}}\text{ }d\omega \text{ }d\varepsilon$

Now I need to find the Lagrange of this function z with some constraint. 
$L(z(\alpha ,\beta ),\mu )=z(\alpha ,\beta )\text{ + }\mu (\alpha +\beta -i)$

I don’t know to how to take the derivative of L with respect to z as z function itself is made of alpha and beta for constraint also.

For example:
$\frac{\partial L(z(\alpha ,\beta ),\mu )}{\partial \alpha }\text{ and }\frac{\partial L(z(\alpha ,\beta ),\mu )}{\partial \beta }$

How do I start the differentiation? Any help on this will be immensely appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you're not meant to find simultaneous solutions of $\partial_\alpha L=0,\,\partial_\beta L=0$ that are the right kind of stationary point?

Comment: Yes these are the stationary points which I want to find. It should be then  $\frac{\partial L(z(\alpha ,\beta ),\mu )}{\partial \alpha }\text{ and }\frac{\partial L(z(\alpha ,\beta ),\mu )}{\partial \beta }$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note first that$$z=\int_{0}^{\beta}\left(\frac{1}{2}\alpha^{2}+\alpha\varepsilon\right)d\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2}\alpha^{2}\beta+\frac{1}{2}\alpha\beta^{2}$$so$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial\alpha}=\alpha\beta+\frac{1}{2}\beta^{2}+\mu,\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial\beta}=\frac{1}{2}\alpha^{2}+\alpha\beta+\mu,\,\frac{\partial L}{\partial \mu}=\alpha+\beta-i.$$Equating the first two of these to 0, and hence to each other, gives $\alpha^{2}=\beta^{2}$ and $\beta=\pm\alpha$. But $\beta=-\alpha$ contradicts any nonzero choice of $i$.